# In Angular select How to change the dropdown list open default upward or downward?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am using the default select dropdown for an Angular application. The dropdown list opens upward or downward randomly. Either it should open upward or downward. Is there any away to achieve this?

[image: dropdown image]

Comment: It is not random. Its position is based on scroll and how much space is above or underneath it

Comment: Thanks @zainhassan Is that any way to set the position always above.